# Can't call posted value from dynamic php and ajax form

Tags: php, forms, dynamic

I built a page that automatically generates new divs when you click "add product." Each div contains a form with unique names and ids. I used this PHP and AJAX multi-level form tutorial to make my forms - http://www.codingcereal.com/2009/09/autopopulate-select-dropdown-box-using-jquery/

Issue is, I can't seem to call the values when submitting the form through PHP. Only reason I can think of is something to do with the forms being dynamically generated.

Any ideas? Let me know if you need more info.

```
        var i = 0;

    $('a#add-product').click(function(event){
        i++;
        $('<div />').addClass('product').attr('id', 'product'+i)
            .append($('<h2><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/product.png" alt="" />Product '+i+'</h2>'))
            .append($('<div class="info-line"><label>Division</label><p><select id="selection-'+i+'"><option value="">- Select a Division -</option><option value="abrasives">Abrasives</option><option value="tapes">Bonding, Surface Protection &amp; Tapes</option><option value="packaging">Packaging</option></select></p></div>'))
            .append($('<div class="info-line"><label>Category</label><p><select id="selectionresult-'+i+'"></select><span id="result-'+i+'">&nbsp;</span></p></div>'))
            .append($('<div class="info-line"><label>Product</label><p><select id="selectionresult2-'+i+'"></select><span id="result2-'+i+'">&nbsp;</span></p></div>'))
            .append($('<a class="remove" href="#add-product" id="remove-product'+i+'"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/remove-product.jpg" alt="" />Remove Product</a>'))
            .appendTo("#products");


            // START OF ADDITIONAL PRODUCT DROP DOWNS

                    $("#selectionresult-"+i).hide();
                    $("#selectionresult2-"+i).hide();

                    $("#selection-"+i).change( function() {
                        $("#selectionresult-"+i).hide();
                        $("#selectionresult2-"+i).hide();
                        $("#result-"+i).html('Retrieving ...');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            data: "data=" + $(this).val(),
                            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>dropdown.php",
                            success: function(msg){
                                if (msg != ''){
                                    $("#selectionresult-"+i).html(msg).show();
                                    $("#result-"+i).html('');
                                }
                                else{
                                    $("#result-"+i).html('<em>No item result</em>');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    $("#selectionresult-"+i).change( function() {
                        $("#selectionresult2-"+i).hide();
                        $("#result2-"+i).html('Retrieving ...');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            data: "data=" + $(this).val(),
                            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>dropdown.php",
                            success: function(msg){
                                if (msg != ''){
                                    $("#selectionresult2-"+i).html(msg).show();
                                    $("#result2-"+i).html('');
                                }
                                else{
                                    $("#result2-"+i).html('<em>No item result</em>');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });

            // END OF ADDITIONAL PRODUCT DROP DOWNS 

            //START OF PRODUCT IMAGE PREVIEWS
                var productSelection = document.getElementById("selectionresult2-"+i);
                var productPreview = document.getElementById("product"+i+"image");

                //Accessories
                $('#selectionresult2-'+i).change(function () {
                    if (productSelection.value == "3M Disc Pad Face 1"){
                        productPreview.src = "<?php echo base_url();?>img/3m-disc-pad1.jpg";
                    }
                    else if (productSelection.value == "Belt 1"){
                        productPreview.src = "<?php echo base_url();?>img/belt1.jpg";
                    }
                    else {
                        productPreview.src = "<?php echo base_url();?>img/spacer.gif";
                    }
                });

                //Belts
                $('#selectionresult2-'+i).change(function () {
                    if (productSelection.value == "3M Disc Pad Face 1"){
                        productPreview.src = "<?php echo base_url();?>img/3m-disc-pad1.jpg";
                    }
                    else if (productSelection.value == "Belt 1"){
                        productPreview.src = "<?php echo base_url();?>img/belt1.jpg";
                    }
                    else {
                        productPreview.src = "<?php echo base_url();?>img/spacer.gif";
                    }
                });


    });
```

Comment: Post your code so we can help you. thanks

Comment: Posted. It's a lot, but it essentially adds a div to the page with fields inside it. Each field is unique based on 'i'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are generating a new form within each div, then when you submit the page, you won't be submitting each of the forms you create, but instead just the form the submit button belongs to.

If you don't put a new form in each div, then all the new fields will belong to the one you submit and you should be able to get their values.

Comment: I misspoke. They are not separate forms in each div, but just select fields, so they do all belong to the same form.

Comment: Does each select option have the value set, i.e. <option value="1">1</option>, or is the value missing?

Also, can you see the fields from the submitted page when you do print_r($_POST); assuming the form is sent via post

Comment: Yes each option is assigned a value in an outside PHP file. I test if the value is submitted by sending it in an email. I use:

$prod1img = $_POST['selection-1'];

I've tried to call all three of the drop downs to see if any work but none do.